# Create and place buttons in a body with flexbox

Tags: css, button, flexbox, header

> Hello, I created a site but I have a problem with my buttons I think
> it comes largely from the fact that I use `<a>` tags (impossible for
> me to create from scratch starting from a  tag If someone can
> explain to me this way of doing things I'm interested because I've
> tried many times and it's impossible for me now
> I want this style of button :  1) Invite & Support button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSUfU.png 2) Login Button in the header section:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFqnF.png But i have this style actually :
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO46l.png

````
        ```<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Poseidon | The Perfect Discord Bot</title>
        
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
            <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="img/favicon.svg">
        
        </head>
        
        <body>
        
            <header class="topbar">
                <a href="#"><img class="header-logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html"></a>
                <nav>
                    <div class="middle">
                        <a href="invite.html">Invite</a>
                        <a href="commands.html">Commands</a>
                        <a href="documentation.html">Documentation</a>
                        <a href="premium.html">Premium</a>
                        <a href="support.html">Support</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login">
                        <a href="#" class="login_btn">Login</a>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        
            <div class="circuit">
                <h1 class="header_title">The Perfect <br>Discord Music Bot.</h1>
                <h2 class="header_second_title">Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
                
                <a href="#" class="invite_btn">Invite</a>
                <a href="#" class="support_btn">Support</a>
        
            </div>
        
        
            <div class="dark">
                <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
                <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
        
                <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
                <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
        
                <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
                <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
            </div>
        
            <div class="circuit">
                <h1>The Perfect Discord Bot.</h1>
                <h2>Poseidon is the only Discord bot you'll ever need!</h2>
            </div>
        
            <div id="footer">
                <div class="logo">
                    <div class="flex">
                        <img class="img" src="img/logo.svg" alt="Poseidon Logo" href="index.html">
                    </div>
        
        
                    <div class="copyright">&#169; Poseidon Bot 2012 - All Rights Reserved.</div>
                </div>
                <ul class="product">
                    <li><b>Product</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Invite</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Commands</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Premium</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="resources">
                    <li><b>Resources</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Docs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Provacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Refunds</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="business">
                    <li><b>Business</b></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="design">
                    designed with <span style="color: red;">&#10084;</span> by <span style="color: #00e09d;">My Discord
                        ID</span></div> <!-- Javascript clickable text // add function js -->
                <div class="social">
                    <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/github.png" href="https://google.fr" /></a>
                    <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-sharp/24/ffffff/discord-logo.png" href="#" /></a>
                    <a href="/"><img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/ffffff/twitter.png" href="#" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
        
        </html>```
````

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, .87);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100%;
}

.topbar {
    height: 80px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(img/background.svg);  
    background-color: rgba(62,62,62, 1);
}

.topbar nav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.topbar nav a {
    color: #9F9F9F;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 21px;
}

.topbar nav a:hover, .topbar nav a.active {
    color: #94C8D0;
}


.header-logo {
  padding: 0px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 25vh;
}


.login_btn {
  margin: auto 25px auto;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #3b3b3b;
}

.circuit {
  background-image: url(img/background.svg);    
  background-color: rgba(62,62,62, 1);
  padding: 192px 0 112px;
}

.dark {
background-color: rgb(35,35,35);
padding: 192px 0 192px;
box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.30), 0 15px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.header_title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 1000;
  font-size: 72px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 72px;
}

.header_second_title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9F9F9F;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 16px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 36px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.header_btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.invite_btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  background-color: #1A9BB6;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
}

.support_btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Inter';
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #282828;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9F9F9F;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9F9F9F;
}

  #footer {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: grid;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr .6fr .6fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "logo product resources business" 
    "social . . design";
}
  
  li {
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 8%;
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1px;
}
  
  .flex {
    display: flex;
}
  
  #footer li a {
    color: rgb(22,145,176);
    text-decoration: none;
}
  
  .logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    grid-area: logo;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .img {
    padding-top: .5rem;
    width: 25vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
  .logo h4 {
    line-height: 1rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
  
  .copyright {
    padding-top: .3rem;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgb(97,97,97);
}
  
  .product {
    grid-area: product;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .resources {
    grid-area: resources;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: .5rem;
}
  
  .business {
    grid-area: business;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px;
}

.social { 
    grid-area: social;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.design {
    grid-area: design;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: right;
```

> To train myself, I decided to reproduce this website:
> https://hydra.bot/ this project taught me many things despite the fact
> that my current project does not correspond to 100% (Very complex for
> me to reproduce it to 100% currently), I block especially on the
> buttons, so if someone can help me I'm interested, thank you in
> advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your invite and support button in another div that has display flex property.

If you make  display flex it is not going to do anything to itself, rather it modifies its child components

```css
.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <a href="#" class="invite_btn">Invite</a>
 <a href="#" class="support_btn">Support</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! But how to design them like on the site: https://hydra.bot/ it's quite particular and not possible to reproduce this style you could do please?

Comment: In fact, I have this result: https://i.imgur.com/XRVAIvm.png but on the Hydra website: https://hydra.bot/ https://i.imgur.com/InjoIzd.png.

Comment: and to place my button like on the site I sent you the closest placement to what I want to get is this one: https://i.imgur.com/M9JRZWB.png :/ you know how I can do please?